# Change apple ID associated with Mac App Store application

Tags: macos, mac, applications, mac-appstore, apple-id

How can I change the Apple ID associated with an application downloaded from the Mac App Store? For example, when I try to update an application, it says for me to login with the account that downloaded the application. Is it possible to change the original Apple ID that was used to download the application to mine? Maybe in the Package Contents?

Comment: To prevent free copy it is not possible to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, you can't do that.

Comment: Really? Surely there would be someway to do this.