# How to "Divorce" Macbook's original Apple ID?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id

An MBA (Macbook Air) is configured with High-Sierra.  It was bought and configured with a relatives Apple ID.  I inherited the MBA: the iCloud account is set to my Apple ID. When trying install Apple updates, both Apple IDs do not work.  Why is this and what is the remedy?

I would like my Apple ID to be authoritative to enable updates from Apple. What would need to be done?

Update: no apps are downloaded from the Apple store.

Comment: Ask your relative to delink the MacBook from their Apple ID. This can be done by logging into iCloud website, go to Find My app and remove the MacBook.

Comment: Are you talking about updating App Store apps? If so, that's separate from iCloud, and each app is permanently linked to the Apple ID is was downloaded with. Only solution is to delete the apps & redownload under your own Apple ID. This may require paying for them again, but you might be able to link the IDs as a [family](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/), and share your relative's purchases.

Comment: If this is about App Store apps, it's a possible duplicate of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129773/app-store-asks-me-for-a-password-but-wont-let-me-change-the-apple-id), [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97543/sign-in-to-download-from-the-app-store-with-a-different-apple-id), and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93550/change-apple-id-associated-with-mac-app-store-application).

Answer (score 1):

Apple covers this expertly.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Once you have a backup, you can restore the documents and not the apps or restore the apps and delete only the ones with an embedded AppleID that’s wrong.

With this procedure you don’t need any access to any AppleID or any previous passwords.